# Leaderboards for Android on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services, facebook-unity-sdk

Hi All I am trying to integrate Leaderboards in my Unit Android Game using Google Play Games Services(GPGS). However it seems like GPGS is going to be deprecated from March 2018(Screenshot attached). Also, the game always crashes on device when I call the Login Authentication for GPGS.
[image]
I was thinking of using FB leaderboard but even that seems to be deprecated. (Screenshot attached)
[image]
I think Firebase is my only option but I am unable to find any resources to implement leaderboards with Firebase. Is there any other alternative/Asset or Firebase resource that some one can please please please point me towards.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Gifts, Requests, and Quests will be the functions that will be deprecated as this [documentation stated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/focusing-our-google-play-games-services.html):

> We've also examined the features that GPGS offers. While developers use engagement and reporting tools extensively, there is lower usage for **Gifts, Requests, and Quests**. We therefore plan to stop supporting Gifts, Requests, and Quests. In order to help developers that do use these features plan for their removal, we will leave them open for 12 months, deactivating them by 31st March 2018. **We'll be continuing support for other features such as Sign-in, Achievements, Leaderboards and Multiplayer**.

They will still continue supporting Sign-in, Achievements, Leaderboards and Multiplayer as these features are frequently used for development.

Hope this helps.